# load the target with update of 2nd row in the source table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

source table

```
id name age
1 a  25
1 a  25
1 a  25
```

target table

```
id name age
1 a  25
1 a  30
1 a  25
```

help me in find out this query

Comment: you do not give enough information

Answer (score 0):

You should use merge statement.

```
Merge into target
using source
on target.id = source.id --and target.name = source.name --if needed
when matched then update 
set target.age=source.age;
```

BUT: you must have unique identifier of rows in the source(it may be composed by multiple columns). For example, for my query to run it need source.id to be unique.